# Restart a script if it's failed part the way through

Tags: shell-script, shell

I would like to re-run the `cap` command if it's failed through the shell script with parameters.

For example, the first command is executed successfully but the second command can't so when I pass the parameter `rerun`, the script will start to execute again second command and continue rest of commands

```
ssh -q $username@$server << EOF
set -e
cd $CT_PATH && cap -q -s instance=$instance mode=quiet diagnostics:all
cap production deploy
cap sales-demo deploy
exit 1
EOF
```

Comment: Does `$CT_PATH` get defined locally or on the remote server? Would you want the `cd $CT_PATH` to be executed with the `rerun` parameter, or should it be just the `cap -q -s instance...` bit that gets ignored? If the first command always fails can you not investigate why it fails and seek to remedy that as part of the script?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
cd $CT_PATH && cap -q -s instance=$instance mode=quiet diagnostics:all
cap production deploy
cap sales-demo deploy
```

to

```
cd $CT_PATH 
[[ $1 = rerun ]] || cap -q -s instance=$instance mode=quiet diagnostics:all
cap production deploy
cap sales-demo deploy
```